# Transcode and decode live stream video with text in Java

Tags: java, video, video-streaming, transcode

I'am looking for a solution in Java language to transcode video from a webcam/stream  and to include some additional text into video and then decode that video. 
For example I have a webcam under the sea. What I like is to add temperature and salinity info to that video.. (I need to save/store video stream + additional text into the same video  (like video + subtitles))

regards

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to write a own video player and show the the additional informations as an overlay to the videostream?

Comment: I have two scenarios: first is a possibility to save stream with temp and salinity into a video file (to file system).. second option is to display video on the webpage + overlayed text (temp and salinity)..  I'am looking for a solution  to save live stream + info about temp and salinity into the same "video" file..

Comment: Why do you do not capture the stream from your website? To modify the media file you can have a look at [Xuggler](http://www.xuggle.com/xuggler/index)

Comment: Using a java ffmpeg wrapper such as https://github.com/bramp/ffmpeg-cli-wrapper and the drawtext filter should work in theory - there do seem to have been issues with streams rather than files though (https://ffmpeg.org/pipermail/ffmpeg-user/2013-September/017309.html) so it would be worth checking with a quick prototype first to make sure it will work.